# django - in what order are called post_migrate handlers?

Tags: django, django-migrations

Let's assume I have two custom apps **APP1** and **APP2** and in both I have registered post_migrate handler. **APP1's** handler creates new permissions and in **APP2's** handler.

I'm trying to create new groups and assign previously created permission to those groups.

Is there any way how to ensure deterministic order of handlers's execution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Register events, sort them in desired order and trigger them just before the code that is relied on this state.

Is there any way to calculate the desired state of your app in some points not relying on the events order? Do it, instead of relying on undefined conditions.